# How to implement Live-chat queue management system?

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, task-queue

I have cases where I have to implement a queue service for Live-Chat application.

I have operators to support clients via live chat, they communicate via websocket, but I need to define an operator for the client, in the first I solved this problem through an in-memory approach when the operator became online I added it to the list of available operators, but now the requirement has become much more difficult in chat support, each company will have a variant of directions, and it may also be that each direction will also have a direction, my main question is how to implement the queue in such situations, are there ready-made libraries?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to get information how to implement such a situation